# Eclipse can't find file in bin directory

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

So I'm trying to read in from a config file in my Eclipse project, but it can't locate the file. Here's my code.

```
public void readConfigFile () {

    //URL url = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myfile.txt");
    //System.out.println(url.getPath());

    URL url = getClass().getResource("/config");
    System.out.println(url);

    try {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(url.toString()));

        //read in values for constants from config file
        System.out.println(BASE_URL);
        BASE_URL = read.readLine().split("\t")[1];
        System.out.println(BASE_URL);

        read.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Read from config file failed. Terminating program");
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

When I run, it prints the `url` variable as:

/Users/myname/Development/workspace/New_API/bin/config

But it fails to find the file when running the BufferedReader command. I get:

```
Read from config file failed. Terminating program
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  
file:/Users/myname/Development/workspace/New_API/bin/config.txt (No such file or directory)
```

When I go to the bin directory of my code however, the config file is there. In the root bin directory, following the exact path given by the URL. What is messing Eclipse up?

Comment: do you have directory at absolute location `/Users/myname/Development/workspace/New_API/bin/config` ? I don't think so shouldn't it be /home/user.name/etcetcetc

Comment: Have you tried copying your file into the root of src folder instead ?

Comment: Don't use FileReader, use `url.openStream()` with an `InputStreamReader`

Comment: Yes, the directory exists. I checked it. And the config file starts in my src folder but is copied to my bin folder at compile time since Eclipse runs programs with bin as root.

Comment: Is this on Mac, PC, or Linux? Just to check for a silly path-separators problem.

Comment: config or config.txt?

Comment: this is on Mac. I went through the path provided by the URL and found the file, so I don't think it's that

Comment: This wouldn't work if your application was packaged in a jar, so don't try to open your resource as a file, but rather as a stream with the method I described above.

Comment: switched to using url.openStream. Works like a charm.Thanks a lot Sotirios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting a resource from the class loader, you're getting it from the classpath, not from the file system. If your application was packaged as a jar, you wouldn't have access to the resource through the `File` or `FileInputStream` APIs since the resource is part of the archive. Instead, you can access the input stream of the resource like so:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/config");

BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
// more...
```